# How to prevent my dog from licking turf at the dog park

Tags: dogs, training

I have an 11 year old non neutered goldendoodle.

We just moved to the city and there is a dog park there with artificial turf. I noticed that he often sniffs the turf very intensely (nose practically touching) and then starts licking the turf after following some kind of scent trail for a bit.

I assume he must be attracted to the smell of one of the other dogs. This unfortunately is very unhygenic and is a behavior I want to prevent.

What is the best way to go about preventing this? I could keep him on a leash and just pull him away every time he tries to lick but I am noticing that he refuses to pee or poop now and focuses exclusively on finding spots in the turf to lick. Which is making our time at the dog park very unproductive.

Comment: How long does your dog show this behavior for now? It could be, that one of the female dog visitors is in heat. Then male dogs act like crazy... But as soon as she will finish the heat, your dog would return to normal.

Comment: What you describe is very natural behavior for dogs and to prevent it you would have to pull your dog away. It's impossible to train your dog to ignore it because the behavior is ingrained deeply in their instincts. Although I do understand that you find it unhygienic, it's certainly not the only unhygienic thing dogs do.